# Getting the total count of replies for all topics in a forum

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, join, eloquent

The database is set up like so:

- Forums($id)
- Topics($id,$forum)
- Posts($id,$topic)

Getting the total topic count was easily done by executing:

```
$total_topics = DB::table("topics")->where("forum", "=", $forum->id)->get()
```

However I'm struggling now to get the total count of posts in a forum. I think joins is the way to go but I'm struggling to get anything working. 
Are Joins the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - You need a JOIN here:

```
$postsCount = DB::table('topics')
  ->join('posts', 'posts.topic', '=', 'topics.id')
  ->where('forum', $forum->id)
  ->count();
```